# ModX Revo pdoResources step by step filtering

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I need to show similar products based on step by step TV filtration using [pdoResources](https://docs.modx.pro/en/components/pdotools/snippets/pdoresources), e.g.
`&tvFilters="product_grape==[[*product_grape]]"`
and if there are no other products with same product_grape exists, than I need to switch to next filter using other condition e.g.
`&tvFilters="product_type==[[*product_type]]"`.
I tried `&tvFilters="product_grape==[[*product_grape]]||product_type==[[*product_type]]"` but it didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that was pretty easy:

```
[[*product_grapesort:is=``:then=`
    &tvFilters=`product_type==%[[*product_type]]%`
`:else=`
    &tvFilters=`product_grape==%[[*product_grape]]%`
`]]
```